# Allow Firebase authentication during a specific time in the day

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication

I have a react app connected to Firebase and I want to allow authentication only during a specific time during the day (for example: from 9am to 4pm) and during the weekdays (from Sunday to Thursday).

Is there a way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

There is no configuration option to set such sign-in times built into Firebase Authentication, nor do I think there's an API that allows you to enable/disable providers programmatically (which would allow you to build it yourself).

I'm also not sure if it would help all that much, as users typically stay signed into Firebase Authentication between app usage sessions. So actively sign in is a relatively rare occurrence in most Firebase apps.

But I think we're looking at a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) here. For example, if you want your app to only be used between certain hours, there are typically other/better ways to do so - but those depend on other resources that your app uses.